# lodash to flatten JSON and show original path

Tags: javascript, json, nested, lodash

I have a JSON object with nested children that I would like to flatten and modify using lodash. Ideally the revised JSON will have a value for the original level the nested children were at and show their original path.

Here is sample JSON:

```
var data = [
    {id: 0, name: 'Australia', children: [
        {id: 10, name: 'Melbourne', children: []},
        {id: 11, name: 'Sydney', children: [
            {id: 100, name: 'Surry Hills', children: []},
            {id: 102, name: 'Darlinghurst', children: []}
        ]},
        {id: 13, name: 'Kambalda', children: []}
    ]},
    {id: 1, name: 'Spain', children: [
        {id: 20, name: 'Barcelona', children: []},
        {id: 21, name: 'Madrid', children: []}
    ]},
    {id: 3, name: 'UK', children: [
        {id: 30, name: 'London', children: [
            {id: 302, name: 'Knightsbridge', children: []},
            {id: 309, name: 'West End', children: []}
        ]},
        {id: 33, name: 'Leeds', children: []},
        {id: 35, name: 'Manchester', children: []}
    ]}
];
```

And the transformed JSON I would like to generate is:

```
 [
    {id: 0, name: 'Australia', level: 0, pathname: 'Australia'},
    {id: 10, name: 'Melbourne', level: 1, pathname: 'Australia > Melbourne'},
    {id: 11, name: 'Sydney', level: 1, pathname: 'Australia > Sydney'},
    {id: 100, name: 'Surry Hills', level: 2, pathname: 'Australia > Sydney > Surry Hills'},
    {id: 102, name: 'Darlinghurst', level: 2, pathname: 'Australia > Sydney > Darlinghurst'},
    {id: 13, name: 'Kambalda', level: 1, pathname: 'Australia > Kambalda'},
    {id: 1, name: 'Spain', level: 0, pathname: 'Spain'},
    {id: 20, name: 'Barcelona', level: 1, pathname: 'Spain > Barcelona'},
    {id: 21, name: 'Madrid', level: 1, pathname: 'Spain > Madrid'},
    {id: 3, name: 'UK', level: 0, pathname: 'UK'},
    {id: 30, name: 'London', level: 1, pathname: 'UK > London'},
    {id: 302, name: 'Knightsbridge', level: 2, pathname: 'UK > London > Knightsbridge'},
    {id: 309, name: 'West End', level: 2, pathname: 'UK > London > West End'},
    {id: 33, name: 'Leeds', level: 1, pathname: 'UK > Leeds'},
    {id: 35, name: 'Manchester', level: 1, pathname: 'UK > Manchester'}
]
```

I have been playing with _.chain, _.flatten and _.pluck and been unable to get anything close.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a simple recursive helper function that would produce an array of arrays, and then use `_.flattenDeep` to flatten it. This does what you want:

```
function flattenMyTree(tree) {
    function recurse(nodes, path) {
        return _.map(nodes, function(node) {
            var newPath = _.union(path, [node.name]);
            return [
                _.assign({pathname: newPath.join(' > '), level: path.length}, _.omit(node, 'children')),
                recurse(node.children, newPath)
            ];
        });
    }
    return _.flattenDeep(recurse(tree, []));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Once I realized I had to update to a later version of lodash to use flattenDeep it worked like a charm for me. Here it is [at work on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lukemcd/hz96z5by/6/).

Answer (score 1):

This one gives you the expected answer but it's not in ideal functional style;
The idea is to start flattening the array from outside. On each iteration of the `while()` loop the array is flattened by one level. Items of that level are appended to the `result` and children of those items are appended to the `children` array. In next iteration we flatten those children. When there are no more items in the `children` array it means that we finished processing the last level. Finally we sort items by `pathname` which effectively groups parents and their children together.

```
var current = data;
var level = 0;
var result = [];
var children = [];

while(current.length > 0) {
    result = result.concat(_.map(current, function(item) {
        if (!_.isArray(item.path)) {
            item.path = [];
        }
        item.path.push(item.name);
        children = children.concat(_.map(item.children, function(child) {
            child.path = item.path.slice();
            return child;
        }));

        item.level = level;
        item.pathname = item.path.join(" > ");

        delete item.path;
        delete item.children;

        return item;
    }));

    current = children;
    children = [];
    level++;
}

result.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.pathname.localeCompare(b.pathname);
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can recursively reduce the `data` collection within a new collection array. Simply tap on each reduce callback for each item with the intention of recursively calling their descendants. The solution below makes use of lazy evaluation to add and remove specific fields.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/MHsnFDFvWzXZc8w6L6Ct?p=preview)**

```
var data = [/*...*/];

function getPathHelper(collection, newCollection, path, level) {
  return _.reduce(collection, function(newCollection, item) {
    path += (path? ' > ': '') + item.name;
    newCollection.push(
      _(item)
        .tap(_.partial(getPathHelper, item.children || [], newCollection, path, level + 1))
        .omit('children')
        .set('pathname', path)
        .set('level', level)
        .value()
    );
    return newCollection;
  }, newCollection);
}

function getPath(collection) {
  return _.sortBy(getPathHelper(collection, [], '', 0), 'pathname');
}

console.log(getPath(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is based on [@mik01aj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32227810/806975), but flattening in each step, and without the default empty array for the `path` parameter:

```js
var data = [
    {id: 0, name: 'Australia', children: [
        {id: 10, name: 'Melbourne', children: []},
        {id: 11, name: 'Sydney', children: [
            {id: 100, name: 'Surry Hills', children: []},
            {id: 102, name: 'Darlinghurst', children: []}
        ]},
        {id: 13, name: 'Kambalda', children: []}
    ]},
    {id: 1, name: 'Spain', children: [
        {id: 20, name: 'Barcelona', children: []},
        {id: 21, name: 'Madrid', children: []}
    ]},
    {id: 3, name: 'UK', children: [
        {id: 30, name: 'London', children: [
            {id: 302, name: 'Knightsbridge', children: []},
            {id: 309, name: 'West End', children: []}
        ]},
        {id: 33, name: 'Leeds', children: []},
        {id: 35, name: 'Manchester', children: []}
    ]}
];

function flattenMyTree(tree) {
    function recurse(nodes, path) {
        return _.flatMap(nodes, function(node) {
            var newPath = _.union(path, [node.name]);
            return _.concat([
                _.assign({
                        pathname: newPath.join(' > '),
                        level: newPath.length - 1
                    },
                    _.omit(node, 'children'))
                ],
                recurse(node.children, newPath)
            );
        });
    }
    return recurse(tree);
}

console.log(flattenMyTree(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```